# Laravel belongsTo Relationship returning null object from with method

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3, relationship, belongs-to

I want to make a list using jQuery datatable. But I have a problem with the following usage.

My Reserve Model:

```
    //Reserve Author
    public function author(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');

    }

    //Reserver
    public function reserver(){

        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'reserver_id');

    }    
    //Stock
    public function stock(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Stock::class, 'reference_id', 'code')->where('company_id', $this->company_id);

    }
```

Following usage is working successfully

```
$reserve = Reserve::find(id);
$reserve->stock->name;
```

But this usage is not working:

```
Reserve::with('reserver','author', 'stock')->get()->toJson();
```

Reserver and author relationship are working in this code but stock is returning null object. What am I doing wrong? I'll be happy if you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a different way. I used to each method and now working.

```
Reserve::with('reserver','author')->get()->each(function($q){
                $q->setAttribute('stock', $q->stock->toArray());
            })->toJson();
```

I would like to use it if there is a better method. Thanks.